I used page.waitForNavigation to wait still the page is load but its not working
Here is my code:
page.waitForNavigation();

// Get the page title after login-

String pageTitleAfterLogin = page.title();
 
Thread.sleep(5000);

// Print the page title after login

System.out.println("Page title after login is: " + pageTitleAfterLogin);

logToAllure("Page title after login is: " + pageTitleAfterLogin);

// Assert the page title after login

page.waitForLoadState(LoadState.NETWORKIDLE);

Thread.sleep(5000);

assertThat(pageTitleAfterLogin).isEqualTo("Home - Demo");

logToAllure("Assertion passed: Page title is: " + pageTitleAfterLogin);



page.waitForNavigation();

// Get the page title after login

String pageTitleAfterLogin = page.title();

I used page.waitForNavigation to wait still the page is load but its not working.

Error : The method waitForNavigation(Runnable) in the type Page is not
applicable for the arguments ()


use this line page.waitForNavigation();

